# Which classes should I use to modify an object without a form and UpdateView involved using Django?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to implement the following functionality on a website I'm developing:

```
1. User 'flags' object by clicking on object specific link.
2. Link leads user to confirmation page.
3. If the user confirms, then a property of the object is changed.
4. User is returned to the original page he/she flagged the object from.
```

The feature would operate in a way similar to django's delete view, except instead of  deleting the object a field for the object would be changed. Alternatively, the function would be similar to an UpdateView, but without a form and a defined field change implemented in the server side code for the object that user is interacting with.

Which combination of django class based views would implement this functionality most gracefully?

Right now, I think that overriding some parts of the UpdateView is the best way to go, and I'll update as I make progress on that front, but I figured other folks may already know how to implement this sort of feature.

UPDATE: 
Currently, implementing something looking

```
class NoFormUpdateView(SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseDetailView):
    template_name_suffix = '_no_form_update'

    def update_fields(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Modifies object fields thenredirects to the success URL.
        """
        self.object = self.get_object()
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        #Do stuff
        if success:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
        else:
            return SomethingWentWrong

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update_fields(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.success_url:
            return self.success_url % self.object.__dict__
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "No URL to redirect to. Provide a success_url.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with your approach of *not* using a FormView. The confirmation actually *is* a Form (even if it does only have a *Confirm* button) -- not a `ModelForm` but a normal django form that confirms your selection.

What I propose doing instead is inherit from `FormView` and also add a `SingleObjectMixin`. Something like this (this is from a Cancel method I'd implemented in a different project but you'll get the idea):

```
class CancelFormView(FormView, SingleObjectMixin):
    queryset = models.Process.all()
    form_class = forms.YesNoForm
    template_name = 'cancel.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = self.get_object()
        yesno = form.cleaned_data['yesno']
        if yesno=='YES':
            # Do something with the object
            # the update_fields method you define should be a method of your object
            obj.cancel()
            messages.info(self.request, u"Cancel ok!")
        else:
            messages.info(self.request, u"Cancel aborted!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("process_view", args=[obj.id] ))
```

As you see, you just need to override the `form_valid` method of your Class and define the `queryset`, `form_class` and `template_name` attributes. You then just update your fields (or do whatever else you like) if the user has actually confirmed that he wants it (he has selected 'YES' in the form). I believe that this is the most DRY way of implementing your requirements.

Comment: I agree, your implementation is better.